# How do I get Eclipse to use NetBeans key bindings?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

I know that one can get Visual Studio key bindings into Eclipse by importing files from other people or installing the C++ add-in. Is there anything out there that will let me import NetBeans key bindings?

Comment: can you please explain what do you want to actually do for which you want to import key bindings, I can't get the meaning of key binding

Comment: Key bindings are also known as shortcuts (e.g. ALT+F4 on Windows will exit most programs).

Answer (score -4):

> One nice thing about NetBeans 6 is that it includes Eclipse key bindings by default. This makes the transition from Eclipse a lot easier.
>   Source: [Netbeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ImprovedEclipseKeyBindings)

So you don't need to change anything, they already have the same key bindings.

Comment: That only helps if you're used to Eclipse and going to NetBeans. I was going the other direction.

Comment: If the key binding are same in both IDEs, it doesn't matter which direction you are changing.

Comment: I'm not sure why you think that's true. Let's say that F5 in NetBeans does "ABC" and F5 in Eclipse does "XYZ". It doesn't help if I can change NetBeans to run XYZ when I press F5 when I need Eclipse to run ABC when I press F5.

Comment: In your example Eclipse and NetBeans do different things, while my quote states that they don't. So your example violates the axiom of my whole argumentation. You are basically assuming that the quote from the NetBeans wiki is wrong, which is partially true. You can read the whole wiki article for details on that.

Comment: What Zian is trying to say is that he's been using NetBeans for some time and is already used to NetBeans shortcuts. Now, he needs to switch to Eclipse and wants to make Eclipse shortcuts like the NetBeans ones. What you're suggesting would work only for new NetBeans users.

Comment: Dous anyone have an actual contribution to make to this post? i am in the same boat. used to NB need to work in eclipse... not even ctrl + F works...

Comment: any answer for this question yet ??